# Android-ui-utils Help

Tags: android, user-interface, icons

I'm trying to use the Android-ui-utils Android Asset Studio with the Pencil GUI prototyping tool.

Everything is working great, and I think this tool will be very helpful. However, I'm having some trouble importing icons from the Asset Studio into the Pencil GUI program.

I've watched the video demo of the program, and cant figure out how they were able to bring the .PNG of the icon from the Asset studio into the Pencil GUI program.

Whenever I try to do so, it either A) wont let me, since its not in .zip format, or in .epc format. But, whenever I try to download the .zip of the icons from the Asset Studio and import it into the Pencil GUI, it says an error occured, and it wasnt able to import it.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get these icons into the Pencil GUI program? I'd really love to use this as a way to prototype the layout and look of my application.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? Possibly shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? It would be very very helpful to me! Thanks everyone!